# file_get_contents doesn't download image from .asp

Tags: php, cookies, file-get-contents

i am working on analyzer kind of script. My script should login the system but system has captcha and this captcha is shown via cookie . When i go the site through  , i can see the captcha but when i go the site via app . It cannot be seen. My code is below.

How can i pass cookie ?

```
$id = "name";
$pw = "pass";
$postfields = "name=$id&password=$pw&Nerden=Forum&securityCode={security_code}&AutoLogin=1&submit=Giriş Yap";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // Get the header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"login_user.asp?ForumID=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$postfields");
curl_exec($ch);
```

This script is webwiz and firstly, i go to forum path(forum/default.asp) and step 2 : i go to login site with ?SESSION_ID=bla bla(program recognizes) however i cannot see the gifs.

Sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

The point of CAPTCHA (an initialism for "Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart") is to prevent automated scripts from doing exactly this.